# Showing image for mobile version of the page while loading

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, mobile

In localhost waiting for the first byte takes about 5 seconds, for live environment it is 200% faster. In mobile version the DOM gets loaded in 0.5 seconds.

At the moment 5 seconds white screen is displayed, then 0.5 seconds loading image and then content. Is it possible to show the image full duration?

## Effort: attempt 1

Using loader image that gets removed when JavaScript has been loaded.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.overlay{
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
.overlay img{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="overlay" >
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Z7IlELT.gif" alt="Loading">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function (){
        $(".overlay").remove();
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Sideeffects

- Loading image is displayed all time

  - If javascript fails to load
  - If javascript is turned off
  - If there is a script bug

## Effort: attempt 2

Using loader image with redirect.

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=default.aspx" />
<style type="text/css">
    .overlay{
        z-index:1;
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
    }
    .overlay img{
        position:absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -16px;
        margin-left: -16px;
    }
</style></head><body><div class="overlay" >
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Z7IlELT.gif" alt="Loading">
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but http://jsfiddle.net/margusmartsepp/Msw6J/1/

Comment: Are you using jQuery mobile?

Comment: @Archer I can use whatever I need. At the moment I use :             'bootbundle.Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js");'.

Comment: I only ask because jQuery Mobile hijacks page links and "ajaxifies" them - that would have a bearing on the solution.  Is it just links that are taking you from one page to another?

Comment: No. It is the "default.aspx" file that is loaded when you enter to the site. During that time I would like to show the loading image (or some feedback, that loading is taking place) to the user (users are impatient).

Comment: Since it's the first page of the site, you can't have anything running before you hit it.  I'd suggest putting an index.html in the folder that has the loading graphic, and have that do a meta redirect to default.aspx.  It's obviously difficult to give advice without seeing what's going on with the page itself, but if it's only localhost that's your problem then is it really a problem?  I have 10-15 second page load times with my main ASP.Net site, but it's less than a second on a real web server, as opposed to the Visual Studio web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Effort: attempt 3

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="gfx/***_57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="gfx/***_114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="gfx/***_72x72.png">    
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="gfx/***_144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" href="gfx/***_60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="gfx/***_120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="gfx/***_76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="gfx/***_152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="gfx/mob_loading_***_320x460.png" sizes="320x460" media="(max-device-width: 480px) and not (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="gfx/mob_loading_***_640x920.png" sizes="640x920" media="(max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="gfx/mob_loading_***_768x1004.png" sizes="768x1004" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="gfx/mob_loading_***_1024x748.png" sizes="1024x748" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="gfx/mob_loading_***_1536x2008.png" sizes="1536x2008" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1025px) and (max-device-width: 2048px) and (orientation:portrait)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="gfx/mob_loading_***_2048x1496.png" sizes="2048x1496" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1025px) and (max-device-width: 2048px) and (orientation:landscape)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. When your page fully downloaded, in 1-2 or 50 seconds it will remove the loading overlay.

In your html file

```
<body>
<img src="loading.gif" class="overlay" />
</body>
```

In your js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".overlay").remove();
});
```